# C# Clone Generic

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

I have a class, `Matrix`, and try to overload the + operator in this class.
The problem is in `matrix1` and `matrix2`, I can't create a clone of this to object. I already even tried to make it using a few `for` loops but it throws an `OutOfMemoryException`.

```
    public static Matrix<T> operator +(Matrix<T> matrix1, Matrix<T> matrix2)
    {
        Matrix<T> m1 = matrix1;
        Matrix<T> m2 = matrix2;
        Matrix<T> result = new Matrix<T>();

        if (m1.Cols != m2.Cols || m1.Rows != m2.Rows)
        {
            if (m1.Rows > m2.Rows)
                m2.Rows = m1.Rows;
            else if (m1.Rows < m2.Rows)
                m1.Rows = m2.Rows;
            if (m1.Cols > m2.Cols)
                m2.Cols = m1.Cols;
            else if (m1.Cols < m2.Cols)
                m1.Cols = m2.Cols;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < m1.Rows; i++)
        {
            result.Add(new List<T>());

            for (int j = 0; j < m1.Cols; j++)
            {
                result[i].Add(new T());
                result[i][j] = Sum<T>(m1[i, j], m2[i, j]);
            }
        }

        result.Cols = m1.Cols;
        return result;
    }
```

I done it in this way

```
    public static List<List<T>> ListClone(List<List<T>> data)
    {  
        var new_data= new List<List<T>>();

        foreach (var list in data)
        {
            new_data.Add(ListClone(list)); 
        }

        return new_data;
    }

    public static List<T> ListClone(List<T> list)
    {
        var new_list = new List<T>();

        foreach(var i in list)
        {
            new_list.Add((T)i);
        }

        return new_list;
    }

    public static Matrix<T> operator +(Matrix<T> matrix1, Matrix<T> matrix2)
    {
        var m1 = new Matrix<T>();
        m1.Cols = matrix1.Cols;
        m1.Rows = matrix1.Rows;
        m1.Data = ListClone(matrix1.data);

        var m2 = new Matrix<T>();
        m2.Cols = matrix2.Cols;
        m2.Rows = matrix2.Rows;
        m2.Data = ListClone(matrix2.data);

        Matrix<T> result = new Matrix<T>();

        if (m1.Cols!=m2.Cols || m1.Rows!=m2.Rows)
        {
            if (m1.Rows > m2.Rows)
                m2.Rows = m1.Rows;
            else if (m1.Rows < m2.Rows)
                m1.Rows = m2.Rows;
            if (m1.Cols > m2.Cols)
                m2.Cols = m1.Cols;
            else if (m1.Cols < m2.Cols)
                m1.Cols = m2.Cols;

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < m1.Rows; i++)
        {
            result.Add(new List<T>());

            for (int j = 0; j < m1.Cols; j++)
            {
                result[i].Add(new T());
                result[i][j] = Sum<T>(m1[i, j], m2[i, j]);
            }
        }

        result.Cols = m1.Cols;
        return result;           
    }
```

but maybe someone have better idiea how to do this easer?

Answer (score 2):

First up, don't make a matrix using a `List<List<T>>`. Just use a `List<T>` and figure out the access operators yourself.

Second, why do you allow the user to set the Row or Column count? Make the matrix immutable and fix the sizes at construction.

```
public class Matrix<T> : ICloneable
    where T : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible, IComparable<T>, IEquatable<T>
{
    private readonly int _rows;
    private readonly int _columns;
    private readonly IList<T> _data;

    public Matrix(int rows, int columns)
    {
        _rows = rows;
        _columns = columns;
        _data = new List<T>(Rows * Columns);
    }

    private Matrix(int rows, int columns, IList<T> data)
    {
        _rows = rows;
        _columns = columns;
        _data = new List<T>(data);
    }

    public int Rows
    {
        get { return _rows; }
    }

    public int Columns
    {
        get { return _columns; }
    }

    public T Element(int row, int column)
    {
        return _data[row * column];
    }

    public object Clone()
    {
        return new Matrix<T>(Rows, Columns, _data);
    }
}
```

The other operators I leave as an exercise

Comment: First  and Second must be like this including to unit test that i have....not my choice

Comment: Well, your `ListClone` method can easily be reduced to one line

`var newData = data.Select(x => new List<T>(x)).ToList();`